# How would I mimic group_concat() with old SQLite?

Tags: php, sqlite, group-concat

I'm using SQLite 3.6.20, which doesn't seem to support group_concat, and the hosting company I use is adamant about not upgrading many systems, so I'm looking for something that mimics the behavior.

My table setup and test data are as follows:

```
sqlite_query($db, 'CREATE TABLE ingredients (id integer primary key, name text not null, description text not null)');
sqlite_query($db, 'create table recipes (name text not null, version integer not null, ingredient_id integer not null, quantity integer not null, yield integer not null, description text not null)');

sqlite_query($db, "insert into ingredients(name, description) values('Pot', 'Tool')");
sqlite_query($db, "insert into ingredients(name, description) values('Mixing Bowl', 'Tool')");
sqlite_query($db, "insert into ingredients(name, description) values('Rutabaga', 'Morsel')");

sqlite_query($db, "insert into recipes(name, version, ingredient_id, quantity, yield, description) values ('Stock', 1, 1, 1, 3, 'Unfulfilling snack')");
sqlite_query($db, "insert into recipes(name, version, ingredient_id, quantity, yield, description) values ('Stock', 1, 2, 1, 3, 'Unfulfilling snack')");
sqlite_query($db, "insert into recipes(name, version, ingredient_id, quantity, yield, description) values ('Stock', 1, 3, 2, 3, 'Unfulfilling snack')");
```

My ultimate result is to select a recipe's name, yield, description, and ingredients, with ingredients being a list of concatenated results such as `[Ingredients] => Pot, Mixing Bowl, Rutabaga`.

After attempting to finagle with things like coalesce(), the closest I'm able to get still only has one of the ingredients in the result:

```
Array
(
    [Yield] => 3
    [Name] => Stock
    [Ingredients] => Pot
    [Description] => Unfulfilling snack
)
1
```

which comes from the following query:

```
$query = sqlite_query($db, "select yield as Yield,
                                   name as Name,
                                   coalesce((select name 
                                             from ingredients where id in (select ingredient_id
                                                                           from recipes r2
                                                                           where name = r2.name
                                                                           and version = r2.version)
                                             ),'') as Ingredients,
                                   description as Description
                            from recipes r
                            where r.name = 'Stock'
                            and r.version = 1
                            group by Name");
```

What's the best I can do with the lack of group_concat()? I'd prefer not to do it via text manipulation with PHP, but I will if necessary.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` seams to be available since [version 3.5.4](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_5_4). Probably PHP driver doesn't implement it...

Comment: That's my guess, too. May need to switch to a more progressive host sometime.

Comment: PHP driver should have nothing to do with that. Maybe you're not really using 3.5.4 version from PHP? PHP still uses 2.8.17 on lots of environments (unfortunately). See what does your PHP tell you when you execute `SELECT sqlite_version();`

Comment: Is there *any* reason to stay with this hosting company?

Comment: Sheesh. Yeah, it's running 2.8.17. That's just frustrating.

The main reason I use them is that I don't do enough serious web projects to go with a pricier host. I'll ask about upgrades, but maybe it's just time to bite the bullet. Thanks, everyone.